# HH:MM Time format RegEx inside array

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm using some masked input plugin, which supports mask as the RegEx array. In my case, I want to validate 24h time format (hh:mm). I'm using now RegEx like this:

```
[/^([0-2])/, /([0-9])/, ':', /[0-5]/, /[0-9]/]
```

First 2 array elements represents hours

```
/^([0-2])/, /([0-9])/
```

Any suggestions how to validate second hour digit? Cause now **25:00** is valid but shouldn't. Need somehow to check first number and if it's 2 - replace [0-9] with [0-3].

Comment: @Kobe no, cause on my case I need to split each character into separate array element

Comment: That plugin only allows a regex to restrict a single char only, not the whole input. Use some other validation feature. Say, on-submit validation, `pattern="(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]"`

Comment: Then regex isn't the solution. Try using normal javascript to validate the input. You can't use this plugin since the 2nd regex is dependant on the first.

Comment: https://github.com/sanniassin/react-input-mask

Comment: Please post an example array. It is now an X/Y problem

Comment: @mplungjan it's on task description

Comment: @Satif how is that helping me to visualise this? Show an actual example of your array. I answered using my imagination

Comment: @mplungjan ^([0-2])([0-9]):[0-5][0-9]  . The ([0-9]) should somehow check previous number

Comment: That is NOT an array of INPUT values

Comment: @mplungjan I think in the end plugin join all array elements into one string

Comment: https://github.com/sanniassin/react-input-mask/issues/75#issuecomment-290718783 & https://github.com/sanniassin/react-input-mask/issues/178#issuecomment-553922142

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be more flexible

```js
const arr = ["07:00", "25:05", "23:59", "00:00"];
const valid = arr.filter(t => {
  const parts = [hh, mm] = t.split(":");
  return !isNaN(hh) && +hh >= 0 && +hh < 24 && !isNaN(mm) && +mm >= 0 && +mm < 60;
});
console.log(valid.length, arr.length, valid.length === arr.length)
```